# AWS EIP Unattached but still billed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, eip, aws-billing

I have checked AWS Billing and I am being billed for an Idle EIP address.
I recently had a non-default VPC with NAT Gateway and VPC that I created.
However I deleted all the resources and the VPC.

When I check under the Elastic IP section in the VPC and EC2 services in the Management Console there are no EIPs showing.

Any advice on how I can resolve this please? There is no resource showing in the CSV file.

Service, Operation, UsageType, Resource, StartTime, EndTime, UsageValue
AmazonEC2,AssociateAddressVPC,EU-ElasticIP:IdleAddress,,05/01/20 00:00:00,05/01/20 01:00:00,1

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As per aws.

An Elastic IP address doesn’t incur charges as long as the following conditions are true:

- The Elastic IP address is associated with an EC2 instance.
- The instance associated with the Elastic IP address is running.
- The instance has only one Elastic IP address attached to it.

You can check the Elastic IP resource under EC2 and release the EIP

Answer (score 1):

As stated the EIP was not showing in the AWS Management Console. Using the CLI I could see the EIP and release it.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-addresses
{
    "Addresses": [
        {
            "PublicIp": "XX.XX.XXX.XXX",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-085acf12e1abb0847",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "PublicIpv4Pool": "amazon",
            "NetworkBorderGroup": "eu-west-1"
        }
    ]
}

$ aws ec2 release-address --allocation-id eipalloc-085acf12e1abb0847
```